# Modeling for sub-accounts at marketplace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am building a marketplace for bookstores.

Model A: single user for each store

```
class User  
  has_one :store
end

class Store
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But it's important that there's not only one User account to manage the bookstore.
The bookstore owner can't be the only one to be able to operate it. He has, say, 3 other employees that should be able to operate it, with different levels of privileges (for example: finances, commercial, customer care).

It's a much simpler version of what Magento has:
[Magento seller sub-accounts](https://marketplace.magento.com/webkul-marketplace-seller-sub-account.html)

I thought about doing this:

Model B: multiple user for each store

```
class User  
  has_many :managements
  has_many :stores, through: :managements
end

class Managements
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store

  # rails g model Management user:references store:references role:integer
  # enum role: { owner: 1, finance: 2, commercial: 3, cx: 4 }
end

class Store
  has_many :managements
  has_many :managers, through: :managements, source: :user  
end
```

This gives multiple users, but it's difficult now to get the owner. (How do I do a scoped has_many_through association?)

Is this the best practice for this business situation?

Or should I go with Model A and plug in sub-accounts later from another angle?

Comment: add an owner scope to the Management class, you can use that to filter the managers on a store to the owner(s)-- store.managers.owner

Comment: [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)
 [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.